# MySql column that auto generates data, longer than UUID

Tags: mysql, database, uuid

I would like to ask if its possible to set up a database table that has a column that auto generates random alphanumerical data that is longer that what UUID can do. I've been using UUID for a while now but I would like to have a longer string of random data in my columns, something similar to that of a token authenticator (around 300+ characters). So when I insert values in columns, this particular column will auto generate data by itself. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Trigger with various calls to md5, sha1, etc.  Salt them for some extra security.  Concatenate them.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I have tried with this but with no success. I googled about md5 and sha1 but is there a certain way to create the trigger?

'DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER testdata
BEFORE INSERT ON testdata
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF new.token IS NULL THEN
    SET new.token = MD5();
  END IF;
END
;;'

Comment: That's the idea.  (That would give you a 32-character string; useful for proof of principle.)  What do  you mean by "no success".

Comment: I should have been more detailed, my bad. I have an error now "Error Code: 1582. Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'MD5'"
I'm using Workbench to construct the database.

Comment: `SELECT MD5(now());` --> "48cda4a3a4a52a2ae728b1b7fe3a88a2"

Comment: All right, works perfectly now! I had to drop my previous UUID trigger that was still present and insert the current one.

Comment: If you want to make it harder for a hacker to discover your technique, add a salt.  For example:  `MD5(CONCAT(now(6), "my secret salt"))`.  https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/80904/what-are-the-differences-between-an-encryption-seed-and-salt